# Write link to images in .js file - Symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 and I have some links to images in my .js file - like this:

```
$(this).attr('src', 'img/icons/black/icon1.png');
```

Of course they don't work this way :( How should I set them?

At first I tried with 
`{{ asset('bundles/acmemy/img/icons/black/icon1.png') }}`, but I soon remembered that I'm not writing in twig file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to link to image using JS file. You can do that by typing 
IMG SRC="images/home.gif" WIDTH="100" HEIGHT="30"

Comment: Thank you, but my question is more focused on the Symfony way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

if images stored in YourBundle/Resources/Public/img/
then after assets:install they will be available by this url 
/bundles/yourbundle/img/*

so the answer is:

    `$(this).attr('src', '/bundles/yourbundle/img/icons/black/icon1.png');`

Answer (score 0):

you may include you assets paths in a javascript object inside your twig file:

`<script>
var images = {'image1': {{ asset('bundles/acmemy/img/icons/black/icon1.png') }} };
<script>`

and then in your script that has to be included after this script tag:

`...
$(this).attr('src', images.image1);
...`

Comment: agree with you! but this is just to give a general adea on how to solve the problem. Best practices come next, dont you think. And who does not create global variables at all? one has to manage to have the least amount of them, and name-spacing them would be better.